# Binomial transform of a scaled version of the catalan numbers.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, catalan-numbers

I was looking at the mathworld entry for Catalan Numbers
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalanNumber.html
and was surprised to find formula (11) there:

(1) $C_n= \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k 2^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}$

where $C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$ is the $n$-th Catalan number.

I tried to prove that formula but failed.
One thing that I tried is the following. Define $D_n = \binom{n}{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$, then formula (1) states that $(C_n/2^n)_n$ is the (alternating) binomial transform of $(D_k/2^k)_k$. Since the alternating binomial transform is self-inverse. Proving (1)  is equivalent to proving the following

(2) $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}=D_n = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k 2^{n-k} \binom{n}{k}C_k$

I haven't been able to prove this formula either.

Could anyone help me find a proof for them?

Answer (score 3):

Since this question has not been answered I will try to give an answer
here.

Suppose we are trying to show that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n
{n\choose k} (-1)^k 2^{n-k} {k\choose \lfloor k/2 \rfloor}
= C_n$$
where $C_n = \frac{1}{n+1}{2n\choose n}$ is the $n$-th Catalan number.

Introduce the integral representation
$${k\choose \lfloor k/2 \rfloor}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^k}{z^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor+1}} \; dz.$$

This gives the following integral for the sum:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z}
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k 2^{n-k}
\frac{(1+z)^k}{z^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor}} \; dz.$$

This integral has two components, call them $A$ and $B$. Component $A$
is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z}
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} {n\choose 2k} 2^{n-2k}
\frac{(1+z)^{2k}}{z^k} \; dz.$$
This is
$$2^{n-1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z}
\left(\left(1+\frac{1+z}{2\sqrt{z}}\right)^n
+ \left(1-\frac{1+z}{2\sqrt{z}}\right)^n
\right) \; dz.$$

Component $B$ is
$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z}
\sum_{k=0}^{\lceil n/2\rceil-1} {n\choose 2k+1} 2^{n-2k-1}
\frac{(1+z)^{2k+1}}{z^k} \; dz.$$
This is
$$-2^{n-1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{\sqrt{z}}{z}
\left(\left(1+\frac{1+z}{2\sqrt{z}}\right)^n
- \left(1-\frac{1+z}{2\sqrt{z}}\right)^n
\right) \; dz.$$

Use the substitution $z=w^2$ where $dz = 2w\; dw$ on both components
to get for A
$$\frac{1}{2} 2^{n-1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^2}
\left(\left(1+\frac{1+w^2}{2w}\right)^n
+ \left(1-\frac{1+w^2}{2w}\right)^n
\right) 2w \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{2} \left(\left(1+w\right)^{2n}
+ (-1)^n \left(1-w\right)^{2n}
\right) \; dw.$$
The  factor of  $1/2$ in  front accounts  for the  fact that  $z$ must
circle  the  origin  twice  for  $w$ to  circle  it  once.  Extracting
coefficients we get for component $A$
$$\frac{1}{2} {2n\choose n} + \frac{1}{2} (-1)^n (-1)^n {2n\choose n}
= {2n\choose n}.$$

We get for component $B$ the integral
$$-\frac{1}{2} 2^{n-1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{w}{w^2}
\left(\left(1+\frac{1+w^2}{2w}\right)^n
- \left(1-\frac{1+w^2}{2w}\right)^n
\right) 2w \; dw
\\ = -\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^n}
\frac{1}{2} \left(\left(1+w\right)^{2n}
- (-1)^n \left(1-w\right)^{2n}
\right) \; dw.$$
Extracting coefficients we get for component $B$
$$-\frac{1}{2} {2n\choose n-1} 
+ \frac{1}{2} (-1)^n (-1)^{n-1} {2n\choose n-1}
= - {2n\choose n-1}.$$
Finally collecting the contributions from both components we get for
our result
$${2n\choose n} - {2n\choose n-1}
= {2n\choose n} - \frac{n}{n+1} {2n\choose n}
= \frac{1}{n+1} {2n\choose n}$$
as claimed.

We have  not made use of  the properties of complex  integrals here so
this  computation  can  also   be  presented  using  just  algebra  of
generating functions.

Apparently  this method is  due to  Egorychev although  some of  it is
probably folklore.

**Addendum.** It  appears we  can treat the  second equation  with the
same method. Suppose we are trying to show that
$${n\choose \lfloor n/2\rfloor} =
\sum_{k=0}^n
{n\choose k} (-1)^k 2^{n-k} C_k$$
where $C_n = \frac{1}{n+1}{2n\choose n}$ is the $n$-th Catalan number.

Introduce the integral representation
$${2k\choose k}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{2k}}{z^{k+1}} \; dz.$$

This gives for the sum the integral
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z}
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k 2^{n-k}
\frac{1}{k+1} \frac{(1+z)^{2k}}{z^k} \; dz
\\ = 2^n \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z}
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k 2^{-k}
\frac{1}{k+1} \frac{(1+z)^{2k}}{z^k} \; dz.$$

Now we have that
$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} \frac{1}{k+1} x^{k+1}\right)'
= \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} x^k = (1+x)^n
= \left(\frac{1}{n+1} (1+x)^{n+1}\right)'$$
and therefore
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} \frac{1}{k+1} x^k
= \frac{1}{x} \frac{1}{n+1}
\left(-1 + (1+x)^{n+1}\right).$$

In the sum integral we have
$$x = - \frac{(1+z)^2}{2z}$$
so we get for the integral
$$- 2^n \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z}
\frac{2z}{(1+z)^2} \frac{1}{n+1}
\left(-1 + \left(1 - \frac{(1+z)^2}{2z}\right)^{n+1}\right)\; dz
\\ = - \frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}
\left(-1 + \left(1 - \frac{(1+z)^2}{2z}\right)^{n+1}\right)\; dz .$$

The first component of this integral is
$$\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(1+z)^2} \; dz = 0.$$

That leaves the second component which is
$$- \frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}
\left(1 - \frac{(1+z)^2}{2z}\right)^{n+1} \; dz 
\\ = - \frac{1}{n+1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}
\left(2 - \frac{(1+z)^2}{z}\right)^{n+1} \; dz 
\\ = - \frac{1}{n+1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}
\left(2z - (1+z)^2\right)^{n+1} \; dz 
\\ = \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}
\left(1+z^2\right)^{n+1} \; dz.$$

Extracting coefficients from this yields
$$\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}
\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} {n+1\choose q}
(-1)^{n-2q} (n-2q+1)
= \frac{1}{n+1}
\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} {n+1\choose q} (n-2q+1)
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} {n+1\choose q}
- \frac{2}{n+1} 
\sum_{q=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} {n+1\choose q} q
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} {n+1\choose q}
- 2 \sum_{q=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac{n!}{(q-1)!(n-(q-1))!}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} {n+1\choose q}
- 2 \sum_{q=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} {n\choose q-1}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} {n+1\choose q}
- 2 \sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor-1} {n\choose q}
.$$

Now there are two cases. Suppose first that $n=2m$ to get
$$\sum_{q=0}^m {2m+1\choose q}
- 2 \sum_{q=0}^{m-1} {2m\choose q}
= \frac{1}{2} 2^{2m+1} 
- 2 \times \frac{1}{2} \left(2^{2m} - {2m\choose m} \right)
= {2m\choose m}.$$
The second case is $n$ odd so that $n=2m+1$ and we get
$$\sum_{q=0}^m {2m+2\choose q}
- 2 \sum_{q=0}^{m-1} {2m+1\choose q}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} \left(2^{2m+2} - {2m+2\choose m+1}\right)
- 2 \times \frac{1}{2} 
\left(2^{2m+1} - {2m+1\choose m} - {2m+1\choose m+1}\right)
\\ = {2m+1\choose m} + {2m+1\choose m+1}
- \frac{1}{2} {2m+2\choose m+1}
\\ = 2{2m+1\choose m}
- \frac{1}{2} \frac{2m+2}{m+1} {2m+1\choose m+1}
= {2m+1\choose m}.$$

We can join these two answer to produce the desired result, which is
$${n\choose \lfloor n/2\rfloor}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here  is another variant to proof OPs claim. As  he already stated, it is sufficient to proof the first identity since the other follows immediately.

> Let $C_n$ be the $n$-th *[Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)*. The following holds true 
>   \begin{align*}
> C_n&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k2^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor}\qquad\qquad n\geq 0\tag{1}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> We separate the  positive and negative  terms  in (1) and write the sum as
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n&(-1)^k2^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}2^{n-2k}
> -\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{2k+1}\binom{2k+1}{k}2^{n-2k-1}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

Note that the Catalan Numbers $C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$ can be written as
\begin{align*}
C_n=\binom{2n}{n}-\binom{2n}{n+1}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> It's a nice circumstance that we can directly relate this representation with the sums of the RHS in (2). We will show the following holds true for $n\geq 0$
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n&\binom{n}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}2^{n-2k}=\binom{2n}{n}\tag{4}\\
> \sum_{k=0}^n&\binom{n}{2k+1}\binom{2k+1}{k}2^{n-2k-1}=\binom{2n}{n+1}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> **First part:** Generating function for $\binom{2n}{n}$ and functional relation
>
> We denote with $f(x)$ the well known generating function of the *[central binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient)*. Note that
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}(-4x)^n
> =\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{2n}{n}x^n
> \end{align*}
>   We can now derive a *functional relation* by evaluating $f$ at $\frac{x^2}{(1-2x)^2}$. We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> f\left(\frac{x^2}{(1-2x)^2}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4\frac{x^2}{(1-2x)^2}}}
> =\frac{1-2x}{\sqrt{1-4x}}
> \end{align*}
>   and we conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x)=\frac{1}{1-2x}f\left(\frac{x^2}{(1-2x)^2}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
>   We use the *[coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series. We obtain from (6) for $n\geq 0$
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^n]f(x)&=[x^n]\frac{1}{1-2x}f\left(\frac{x^2}{(1-2x)^2}\right)\\
> &=[x^n]\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{x^{2k}}{(1-2x)^{2k+1}}\\
> &=[x^n]\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{2k}{k}x^{2k}\sum_{l\geq 0}\binom{-(2k+1)}{l}(-2x)^l\\
> &=[x^n]\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{2k}{k}x^{2k}\sum_{l\geq 0}\binom{2k+l}{l}(2x)^l\\
> &=\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{2k}{k}[x^{n-2k}]\sum_{l\geq 0}\binom{2k+l}{l}(2x)^l\\
> &=\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{n}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}2^{n-2k}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\Box
> \end{align*}
>
> and (4) follows.

$$ $$

> **Second part:** Generating function for $\binom{2n}{n+1}$ and functional relation
>
> Similarly to the first part we define a function $g(x)$ to be the generating function for $\binom{2n}{n+1}$. Since the generating function $C(x)$ for the Catalan numbers $C_n$ is known to be 
>   \begin{align*}
> C(x)=\frac{1}{2x}\left(1-\sqrt{1-4x}\right)
> \end{align*}
>   it follows from relation (3)
>   \begin{align*}
> g(x)&=\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{2n}{n+1}x^n
> =\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}-\frac{1}{2x}\left(1-\sqrt{1-4x}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{2x}\left(\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}+1\right)\tag{7}
> \end{align*}
>
> Now we proceed slightly different to (1). We consider the generating function $p(x)$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> p(x)&=\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{2k+1}{k}x^{2k}\\
> &=\sum_{k\geq 0}(2k+1)C_kx^{2k}\\
> &=D\left(\sum_{k\geq 0}C_kx^{2k+1}\right)\\
> &=D\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x^2}}{2x}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{2x^2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}-1\right)
> \end{align*}
>   with $D$ the differential operator. Evaluating $p$ at $\frac{x}{1-2x}$  results in
>   \begin{align*}
> p\left(\frac{x}{1-2x}\right)&=\frac{1}{2\left(\frac{x}{1-2x}\right)^2}
> \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4\left(\frac{x}{1-2x}\right)^2}}-1\right)\\
> &=\frac{(1-2x)^2}{2x^2}\left(\frac{1-2x}{\sqrt{1-4x}}-1\right)
> \end{align*}
>   We compare this expression with $g(x)$ in (7) and observe
>   \begin{align*}
> g(x)=\frac{x}{(1-2x)^2}p\left(\frac{x}{1-2x}\right)
> \end{align*}
>   Expanding the RHS of the last equation we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^n]g(x)&=[x^n]\frac{x}{(1-2x)^2}p(\frac{x}{1-2x})\\
> &=[x^n]x\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{2k+1}{k}\frac{x^{2k}}{(1-2x)^{2k}+2}\\
> &=[x^n]\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{2k+1}{k}x^{2k+1}\sum_{l\geq   0}\binom{-(2k+2)}{l}(-2x)^l\\
> &=[x^n]\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{2k+1}{k}x^{2k+1}\sum_{l\geq   0}\binom{2k+1+l}{l}(2x)^l\\
> &=\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{2k+1}{k}[x^{n-2k-1}]\sum_{l\geq   0}\binom{2k+1+l}{l}(2x)^l\\
> &=\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{n}{2k+1}\binom{2k+1}{k}2^{n-2k-1}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\Box
> \end{align*}
>   and (5) follows, which completes the proof.

**Note:** I found the functional equation of $f$ which is the essence of the proof in J. Riordans classic *[Combinatorial Identities](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471722758)*.